# Swift to Objective-C Syntax

Tags: objective-c

Could anybody convert this line of code to Objective-C for me? It's written in Swift and I'm not too familiar with the syntax.

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: So, you know that the official Apple documentation has the Swift & Objective-C syntax literally presented side-by-side for everything available in their libraries, right?

Comment: I thought this may be the case, but I'm a new student at Bloc, and I found this piece of code that I absolutely needed for a project I'm working on. I plan to dive into swift once I know the ins and outs of objective-c. I didn't mean to step on any toes here, I just needed a particular piece of code translated as quickly as possible.

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If self is an UIViewController

```
[self presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice! I updated the question with a few more lines of code. Could you help me out here?

Comment: @AlexBlair, the properties are set the same way, except `false` will be `NO`. The instantiation of the UIVIewController will be using a generic or custom init method `UISearchController* searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] init];`

Answer (score -1):

```
[self presentViewController:searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: it's better to use `nil` instead of `NULL`